# How to connect Mailchimp to opencart 2.3.02?

Tags: php, opencart, mailchimp

Did anyone knows any solution to integrate mailchimp to opencart 2.3.0.2?. I found only paid solution. 
If you know a website or video teaching how to integrate, tell me please

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Mailchimp Api to get/push your data using a custom module.
That custom module can be build with the api endpoints

Link Mailchimp Api : https://developer.mailchimp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you have no clue about where to even start, save yourself the time, just use the paid solution, it is not expensive: https://mailchimp.com/integrations/opencart-mailchimp-integration/

Comment: All the best extensions for opencart are paid and if you work with magento or wordpress is free :(

Comment: Magento extensions are usually the most expensive. Do you think it's realistic to expect developers to do loads of work to help your business for free? How will they feed their children and pay their bills?

Comment: I'm developer... Actually I want to ask questions about the code and if I have something ready and I would compare the code for questions. Why do u say: magento extensions are expensive, for mailchimp is free - https://mailchimp.com/help/connect-or-disconnect-mailchimp-for-magento-2/

Comment: "I'm developer" then begin building and ask when you get stuck.

Comment: "Why do u say: magento extensions are expensive" they are. Just because one is free doesn't make the statement untrue.

Comment: "then begin building and ask when you get stuck" what happened with "Do you think it's realistic to expect developers to do loads of work to help your business for free? How will they feed their children and pay their bills?" Like you said, its not to simple. And its not only one, it's a lot of extension for magento is free and for oc no. Anyway...